# CodeIgniter is only executing JS once inside a loop

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, foreach, modal-dialog

I am using CodeIgniter to display a list of items from the database. I want to delete an item based on it's ID. This is not a problem and works fine without the modal box.

My issue is that I am using a jQuery plugin called reveal (http://goo.gl/3lzRN) to add a modal box to confirm deletion. This works for the first item in the list, but the others have the same ID as the first.

```
<a href="pages/<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="delete">
    <i class="icon-cancel"></i><span class="delete_tooltip">delete page</span>
</a>

<aside id="modal">
    <header id="delete_page">Delete Page</header>
    <article id="modal_content">
        <p>
        Are you sure you want to delete the page<br />'<?php echo $row->title ?>'?
        </p>

        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>

        <p>
        <a href="pages/delete_page/<?php echo $row->id; ?>" >
            <i class="icon-cancel"></i>Delete
        </a> <a href="pages/#" class="modal_cancel">Cancel</a> 
        </p>
    </article>
</aside>
```

Above is the link to open the modal box, and the content in it. These are within a foreach loop, but as I know the loop works fine, I haven't posted it.

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID ... ?

Comment: God dammit, now I feel stupid. Thanks David. Though now it loads all boxes. I should have mentioned that I don't know Jquery or JS all that well.

Comment: Use classes still, but find the correct one to activate based on a specific ID (Each one being unique), so it would probably be something like: id="modal-1" where 1 is the $row->id ... that way you shouldn't get any duplictes :-) If you want further help, put it in a jsfiddle and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @David perhaps you can convert your comments into an answer, so it can be accepted by the asker?

Comment: Thanks David, http://jsfiddle.net/Z7vHT/ that is the HTML I have (minus the dynamic generated ID's and titles) and the JS that calls the plugin. The plugin is available at http://goo.gl/3lzRN

Comment: Please check the answer I've submitted, it has the ammended jsfiddle (It has the PHP bits in there too, so it probably won't work on the fiddle!)

Comment: don't use same `ID` for multiple element, instead of `ID` use `class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a class instead of an ID. IDs should only be present once per page, and thus this is what is causing your problem.

Classes are used for items that appear more than once (reusable items).

I'd recommend also assigning a *unique* id to the modals too, something like id="modal-1" where 1 is the ID from $row->id;

This way, each of your modals can be accessed through the class easily, but can be uniquely identified by their ID.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7vHT/1/ That should fix your issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. Nothing happens now. No boxes appear. It seems this plugin does not play nice.

Comment: You were right, I missed one. You are a star. Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexMcCabe - I take it thats a screenshot of it working? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use same ID for multiple elements on page. ID is a unique identifier, thus most browsers will only take the first element into consideration, while others will return unexpected values.

You should be using classes for those elements that are to have the same functionality,

Comment: Thanks to David above I realised this, and it's one of those things that you sometimes overlook...Thank you as well. The only issue I have now is that it loads all the modal boxes when I click only one of the links. I don't know jQuery or JS all that well.

Comment: you may need to update your modal box classes and give each box a special one - for instance `<aside class="modal1">` etc.